# Invoking the real Back Button Icon - Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

The code below manages the Back button, but obviously puts the word Back up in lieu of the Icon:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "segueBack")
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

How do I get iOS the invoke the back button icon? In Cocoa there was a call along the lines of:

```
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACK_BUTTON_DEFAULT_ICON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own button object in order to set its title. You can initWithTitle or create it and then set the title afterward.

The backBarButtonItem only affects its child views that are pushed on top of it in the navigation stack. Depending on your design the root view can't be popped any further and can't have a back button. Though, you can affect the leftBarButtonItem.

Create a UIBarButtonItem instead of setting the title of the existing one.

For example:

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem (title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "segueBack")
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

Set it on the "parent" view controller, where the Back button will return to.

Comment: Hmm, that is the perceived wisdom but if you put these in the VC class for the current view you can override the Title/Backbutton with whatever you want. There must be a way of forcing the standard image. But if you leave it as "" it will use the inmate inherited BackButton.

Comment: And it's even weirder. If you have nothing in the View (say just the title) it picks up the previous. If you have something in the view it behaves differently.

Comment: If you want to use a push transition but show a normal-looking button with the arrow, you can do this in your second VC's viewDidLoad():  -`navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false`. You can play with the type of transitions too. For example changing your segue type to "Present Modally" or not in the storyboard. It's all to do with the nav stack and parent/child inheritance. Another thing you can experiment with is embedding your second VC in its own navigation controller, using unwind segues etc.